# How do I get a table controller to display a foreign key association? [Rubymine 2020.2.3, Ruby.2.7.2p137, gem 3.1.2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am near the deadline on a college project (3 weeks) and I have had encountered several issues. It being a project course, I can't always refer to my tutor.

Earlier I have asked a question that has provided solutions for a table that did not have a foreign key,  thanks to the kind people on this site, it is finally resolved. A more long-standing issue is getting table to work with a foreign key, one of these tables would never display a single data record at the index.

This is the Create method of the 'Shipment' table controller where I try to create an association to the 'Courier' to which the Shipment belongs_to and the Courier has_many of. The following lines are per the document instructions of my course:

```
 @cour_id=params[:shipment][:courier_id]
@courier=Courier.find(@cour_id)
@shipment=Shipment.new(params.require(:shipment).permit(:tracking_number, :shipment_date))
@shipment.courier<< @courier
@shipment.save
redirect_to shipment_path(@shipment)
@shipment=Shipment.new(shipment_new_path)
if @shipment.save
  redirect_to(:controller=>'shipment' ,:action=>'index')
else
  render('new')
end
end
```

The associations appears to be necessary because one of the forms at the shipment/new.erb.html is a drop down of a set of Courier records from one of it's table columns. Which appears to display from that form within that page.

The issue I come across is in the line '@shipment.courier << @courier', the '<<' is treated as an undefined method for nil:NilClass. I have tried variations of this line of code (@shipment.couriers..., @shipment.courier.id...), but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

[screencap of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nn9Hc.png)

I suspect that a more pressing problem is at play from this particular table, I noticed that even from the back end, the table wouldn't appear to save new records. Even though there is nothing particularly different from this table compared to others. I have initially attributed it's inability to pass data as due to a misalignment between table associations, now I interpret it as an issue of not being able to function without adequately being connected to the id of the Courier table.

The question stands, how do I get the associations to function?

Comment: should be `@shipment.courier = @courier`, not `@shipment.courier<< @courier`

Comment: Edited the tags. Your IDE / tools are really irrelevant here. The `rubymine` tag should really be used for answers that concern the editor itself. And `rubygems` is for questions regarding the `gem` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really just a standard run-of-the-mill nested resource that you're describing. I really don't know what to make of the jumble of code in your question - but the Rails way of doing this would be:

```
resources :couriers do
  resources :shipments, 
     only: [:index, :new, :create]
end
```

```
class ShipmentsController < ApplicationController
  # use callbacks to avoid repitition
  before_action :set_courier, only: [:new, :create, :index]

  # GET /couriers/1/shipments
  def index
    @shipments = @courier.shipments
  end

  # GET /couriers/1/shipments/new
  def new
    @shipment = @courier.shipments.new 
  end

  # POST /couriers/1/shipments
  def create
    @shipment = @courier.shipments.new(shipment_params)
    if @shipment.save
      # shorthand for courier_shipments_path(@courier)
      redirect_to([@courier, :shipments])
    else
      render(:new)
    end
  end

  private

  # use a private method instead of repeating yourself
  def shipment_params
    params.require(:shipment)
          .permit(:tracking_number, :shipment_date)
  end

  def set_courier
    @courier = Courier.find(params[:courier_id])
  end
end
```

```
# app/views/shipments/new.html.erb
<%= form_with(model: [@courier, @shipment]) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :tracking_number %>
    <%= f.text_field :tracking_number %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :delivery_date %>
    <%= f.date_field :delivery_date %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```